# Repeating a Wintask macro over and over and over

Tags: automation, macros

I'm using WinTask to run a macro for something.  I need it to start over as soon as it finished.  I just downloaded it a couple of minutes ago so I really only know the basics.  I only need it for one task today (a long and boring one at that).

Thanks if you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I added:

```
repeat
```

at the top and

```
until 1=2
```

at the end, it's crude, but it works.

Thanks anyways, love you SU and SO!